# Как выбрать список сущностей с кастомным набором полей через Criteria API, если у сущности есть связанная коллекция других сущностей?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Как выбрать список сущностей с кастомным набором атрибутов через Criteria API, если у сущности есть связанная коллекция других сущностей?
Здравствуйте. Есть сущность, у которой одно из полей - это коллекция других сущностей:

```
class UserEntity {
private Long id;
private String name;
private Set<GroupEntity> groups;
private byte[] avatar;
//....
}
```

Необходимо получать список этих пользователей через Criteria API, причём выбирать нужно не все поля (одно поле надо исключить - avatar). Но поле с коллекцией сущностей должно попадать в выборку.

Искал в интернете - не нашёл.

Comment: Можете аватар пометить как Lazy поле, тогда оно будет инициализироваться только по запросу.

Comment: `поле с коллекцией сущностей должно попадать в выборку` а можете привести пример выборки, что есть в БД и что ожидаете получить?

Comment: @MrFylypenko БД - это другой вопрос, мы говорим в рамках объектной модели. Пробовал делать через multiselect так:                 final Root<SysUserEntity> root = criteriaQuery.from(SysUserEntityc.class);

        criteriaQuery.multiselect(
                root.get("login"), root.get("password"), root.get("lastName"),
                root.get("firstName"), root.get("middleName"), root.get("contactPhone"),
                root.get("email"), root.get("locked"), root.get("descr"),
                root.get("needResetPassword"), root.get("groups"), root.get("versionNumber")
        );

Comment: @MrFylypenko Но это вызывает ошибку.

Comment: @Z.John Какую именно аннотацию имеете в виду? Ставил Lazy только на коллекции

Comment: @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) private byte[] avatar;

Comment: `@Basic` не очень [явно работает](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112508/basicfetch-fetchtype-lazy-does-not-work), лучше реализовать через связь один-к-одному. Какая объектная модель я не знаю, поэтому и не пишу ответ как делать запрос, [вот пример join и fetch join](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tip-left-join-fetch-join-criteriaquery/), одним запросом можно выбирать дочерние сущности одним запросом